# Windows Batch commands to copy multiple file to multiple subdirectories

Tags: batch-file

ok so I'm on Windows... hmm 7 still

I tried to find how to copy files from one directory to multiple, but I only found how to copy from various into one or one file only to various. I need to copy various file to various directories in function of the file name.

So I have this group of documents, I have a beautiful excel list which indicate for which document where I should send them so I tried a quick concatenate to have a batch file 
The command line open well but it repeat the first line ad libitum

Can you explain to me where is my error ?

```
xcopy "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\64340C-P3-4J01001A-PCS430033-01-Rev1.pdf" "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\PE3-L-S04-00002" /z /i

xcopy "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\64340C-P3-4J01001B-PCD430004-01-Rev1.pdf" "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\PE3-L-S04-00013" /z /i

xcopy "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\64340C-P3-4J01001B-PCD430004-03-Rev1.pdf" "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\PE3-L-S04-00013" /z /i

xcopy "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\64340C-P3-4J01001B-PCD430005-01-Rev1.pdf"    "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\PE3-L-S04-00013" /z /i
```

or

```
xcopy 64340C-P3-4J01001A-PCS430033-01-Rev1.pdf \PE3-L-S04-00002 /z /i
```

or

```
xcopy C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\64340C-P3-4J01001A-PCS430033-01-Rev1.pdf c:\Users\me\Documents\Test\PE3-L-S04-00002 /z /i
```

[image]

Comment: Hmm - at least we have some language in common, but how "ad libitum" ("at one's pleasure") fits into the scenario, I really can't see. Perhaps the problem is that the `/i` switch for `xcopy` should be examined. It instructs "If destination does not exist and copying more than one file, assumes that destination must be a directory". Since the source appears to be a single file, not "more than one", then this would seem to be superfluous. Perhaps modifying to destination to (eg) "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\PE3-L-S04-00002\" would achieve the desired result (note terminal `\\`

Comment: I think I finally found my error ... as first I had an error in my first bat ("" for my document too), I didn't change directly but in copy.. and let all my bat copy in the same folder... once I quit them it worked with    xcopy 64340C-P3-4J01001A-PCS430033-01-Rev1.pdf "C:\Users\me\Documents\Test\PE3-L-S04-00002" /z /i